# Есть ли в PHP классе , правила очередности декларирования , public, private и protected методов?

Tags: php

Есть большой класс с многими методами ,  первым у меня декларирован

```
    public function index()
    {
      //CODE
    }
```

в классе  много private и protected  методов,  для меня логично что первым декларируется метод index()  хоть он и public.

> Если первым будет private метод Update() как-то нелогично

Помогите разобраться  с очередностью декларирования  констант, полей и public, protected, private методов в PHP  классе.

Если есть ссылки буду рад прочитать.

Comment: Нет таких правил. Даже нет ограничения на использование функции и её объявление (как, например, в С++). Почитайте https://www.php-fig.org/psr/ первые два стандарта

Comment: некоторые среды разработки, говорят о том, что допустимое количество строк в классе 200, а длина строк метода, 20. Но я думаю это все их инициатива.

Comment: @And, это всё настраиваемые показатели code style.

Comment: Для себя можете конечно как-то сортировать: сперва переменные константы, потом private потом protected потом public. Ваш (index()) не будет тут в самом верху. Потому что у index() никаких привилегий нет, должен быть вместе с кучкой пабликов, можете сделать его первым

Comment: @vp_arth, я об этом же. Это сами контролят, вопрос бы был бы в другом, если бы задался в какой последовательности и что первым загружается =)

Answer (score 0):

Ни каких правил и ограничений нет.
Я при программировании группирую переменные, константы по смыслу и отмечаю символом _ приватные переменные

Comment: Расскажите, пожалуйста, для чего вы помечаете приватные переменные? А protected помечаете ли?

Comment: @vp_arth protected помечается `__` по логике. по сабжу, я тоже иногда помечаю через `_` но не private, а публичные методы смысл у которых более системного характера (если кратко).

Comment: Понимаю что  правил нету , но что является правильным стилем программирования в  этом вопросе.

Comment: В php идентификаторы, начинающиеся с `__` давно объявлены зарезервированными за языком и строго не рекомендуются к использованию для собственных нужд. PSR2 также не рекомендует (`SHOULD NOT`) обозначать видимость свойств в имени: `Property names SHOULD NOT be prefixed with a single underscore to indicate
protected or private visibility.`

Comment: @a_mine каждый по своему "чешет пяткой за ухом" в программировании. Начитаются умных книжек всяких забугорных авторов и перенимают/продвигают понятия прекрасного и легко читаемого кода. Первое чем нужно руководствоваться - рекомендациями разработчиков языка, второе - здравым смыслом (в каждом конкретном случае).